# If $S$ and $T$ are sets of all linear combinations, prove that $S=T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $S$ is set of all linear combinations of vectors $v_1,v_2, \cdots, v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $T$ is set of all linear combinations of vectors $v_1,v_2, \cdots v_{k-1}, cv_k$ for some scalar $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $S=T$.

Here I tried (I assume that the scalars on $S$ and $T$ are same, say $m_i \in \mathbb{R}$).

Let $S=\lbrace m_1v_1,m_2v_2,\cdots m_kv_k \rbrace$ and $T=\lbrace m_1v_1,m_2v_2,\cdots m_{k-1}v_{k-1}, m_kcv_k \rbrace$. Let

$A = S - T$. Then,
$A = m_kv_k - m_kcv_k = m_kv_k(1-c)$.
I'm stuck here. Thanks for help in advanced.

Comment: Note that the problem doesn’t say that the vectors are linearly independent, so you can’t assume that the coefficients of the two linear combinations match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that $c\ne0$; otherwise, the statement is false.

If $v\in S$, then you can write $v$ as $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_{k-1}v_{k-1}+a_kv_k$. But then$$v=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_{k-1}v_{k-1}+\frac{a_k}c(cv_k)\in T.$$And if $v\in T$, then you can write $v$ as $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_{k-1}v_{k-1}+a_k(cv_k)$. But then$$v=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_{k-1}v_{k-1}+(ca_k)v_k\in S.$$

Comment: Worth to note that OP:s method doesn't work since he assumes the $m_1,\dots,m_k$ are the same in both $S,T$ when they could be different. And also that if $c=0$ it's only true if $v_k$ is linearly dependent on $v_1,\dots,v_{k-1}$.